# Robust regression after using Box cox transformation

Tags: regression, data-transformation, robust

Is that making sense to apply robust regression after using Box Cox transformation. In my data, it seems by using log transformation I can improve the model since I have the violation of the assumptions. Now my question is after that I should apply OLS regression or Robust regression?

Comment: Maybe not! A few outliers could have a huge influence on the estimation of the transform parameter, so you probably should use robust regression already in estimating the box-cox transform

Answer (score 0):

Take the log if taking the log makes substantive sense in your application. E.g. it often makes sense to take logs of variables based on money, because we often think of money that way. E.g.  The difference between a \$100,000 house and a \$200,000 is "bigger" than the difference between a \$1,000,000 house and a \$1,100,000 house.

Use some form of robust regression if it makes sense for the model on the variables you want to use.